# How can I transform certain values in an object while ignoring some of the keys?

Tags: javascript

I want to loop through Objects in an array with different keys, without using a for-each loop:

```
   [ { id: 1,
    ip: 'xx.xxx.xx.xx',
    mn1: '',
    mn2: '',
    mn3: '',
    mn4: '',
    mn5: '',
    mn6: '',
    mn7: '' },
  { id: 2,
    ip: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx',
    mn1: '',
    mn2: '',
    mn3: '',
    mn4: '',
    mn5: '',
    mn6: '',
    mn7: '' },
  { id: 4,
    ip: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx',
    mn1: '',
    mn2: '',
    mn3: '',
    mn4: '',
    mn5: '',
    mn6: '',
    mn7: '' } ]
```

I want to check every column mn for a length value then update it with some information, I can just do if else condition, but I think there is a better way of doing this. I tried using `Object.entries` then for loop, but it won't work because of id and ip columns.

Comment: When you find yourself using variable/key names ending in numbers its a good indication that you probably want an array like `mn[1], mn[2], etc`.

Comment: have you looked at `Object.keys` ?

Comment: You can use [`for (var item in obj){ .. }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: what information do you want to update `mn*` keys with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work for you? This solution takes a functional approach to your problem, and avoids explict use of the `for-loop` construct:

```js
var input = [ { id: 1,
    ip: 'xx.xxx.xx.xx',
    mn1: '',
    mn2: '',
    mn3: '',
    mn4: '',
    mn5: '',
    mn6: '',
    mn7: '' },
  { id: 2,
    ip: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx',
    mn1: '',
    mn2: '',
    mn3: '',
    mn4: '',
    mn5: '',
    mn6: '',
    mn7: '' },
  { id: 4,
    ip: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx',
    mn1: '',
    mn2: '',
    mn3: '',
    mn4: '',
    mn5: '',
    mn6: '',
    mn7: '' } ];
    
var output = input.map(object => {
  
  return Object.entries(object).reduce((result, entry) => {
    
    let key = entry[0];
    let value = entry[1];
    
    if(key.startsWith('mn')) {
      
     value = `updated value for ${ key }`;
    }    
    
    result[key] = value;
    return result;
    
  }, {});
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the name of the key before you modify it.

Does this help? Try it out by running the code snippet.

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    ip: 'xx.xxx.xx.xx',
    mn1: '',
    mn2: '',
    mn3: '',
    mn4: '',
    mn5: '',
    mn6: '',
    mn7: ''
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    ip: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx',
    mn1: '',
    mn2: '',
    mn3: '',
    mn4: '',
    mn5: '',
    mn6: '',
    mn7: ''
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    ip: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx',
    mn1: '',
    mn2: '',
    mn3: '',
    mn4: '',
    mn5: '',
    mn6: '',
    mn7: ''
  }
];

console.log('BEFORE', JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));

for (const item of arr) {
  for (const key of Object.keys(item)) {
    if (!key.startsWith('mn')) continue;
    
    // know if the code gets here then it's an `mn` key
    
    // you can do logic here on the key
    // and then manipulate the result
    
    item[key] = 'changed';
  }
}

console.log('AFTER', arr);
```

Comment: I think the goal was to avoid for loops

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries`, `Array.prototype.filter`, and `Array.prototype.forEach` to your advantage.

```js
const transform = value => `transformed-${value}`;
const arr = [{ id: "id", ip: "ip", otherKey: "other" }];
arr.forEach(obj => {
    Object.entries(obj)
        .filter(([key]) => key !== "id" && key !== "ip")
        .forEach(([key, value]) => (obj[key] = transform(value)));
});
console.log(arr)
```

This starts to get verbose if you can't use the latest ECMAScript features, though:

```js
var transform = function(value) { return "transformed-" + value };
var arr = [{ id: "id", ip: "ip", otherKey: "other" }];
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    Object.entries(obj)
        .filter(function(keyValue) {
            var key = keyValue[0];
            return key !== "id" && key !== "ip";
        })
        .forEach(function(keyValue) {
            var key = keyValue[0],
                value = keyValue[1];
            obj[key] = transform(value);
        });
});
console.log(arr)
```

If you're stuck on a project without Babel, your best bet may be your original suggestion.

```js
var transform = function(value) { return "transformed-" + value };
var arr = [{ id: "id", ip: "ip", otherKey: "other" }];
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(function(keyValue) {
        var key = keyValue[0],
            value = keyValue[1];
        if (key !== "id" && key !== "ip") {
            obj[key] = transform(value);
        }
    });
});
console.log(arr)
```